# How to read the details of particular file using c#

Tags: text-files, c#-2.0

How to read the details of particular sections using c#...

i am new to c# and i have to read the details from a text file based on the sections marked between square brackets "[]".. the file looks like

`[Header]

This is the header info for the file

[Body]

This is the body information for the provided file

and it contains many information for the file

[Summary]

Summary for the file.`

i need to read each of these sections details (eg. [Header], [Body])..

any help in this direction is highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the text between those headers does not contain brackets you can do it this way:

```
Dictionary<String,String> content = new Dictionary<String,String>();

String text = @"[Header]
This is the header info for the file
[Body]This is the body information for the provided file and it contains many information for the file
[Summary]Summary for the file.";

foreach (String section in text.Split("[".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    String[] sectionParts = section.Split(']');
    content.Add(sectionParts[0], sectionParts[1]);
}
```

The `Dictionary` will contain the content of your File as header-text-pairs